# rake says "cannot load such file -- spec"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I am using:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Rails 3.2.12
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
- rake rake-10.0.4

When I run `rake db:create` I get this error message:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- spec
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/home/lcastano/dev/roommateflatfinder/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/lcastano/dev/roommateflatfinder/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:589:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I tried uninstalling rake and re-installing it. Anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: please edit your post,it is very unclear.

Comment: What does your `Gemfile` contain?

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

You have an invalid statement in your Rakefile or Gemfile. You probably meant 'rspec' or 'rspec-rails' instead. Rake itself is telling you so:

> cannot load such file -- spec

### Solution

Remove the reference to "spec" in your Rakefile or Gemfile, or replace the problematic line with the correct name of the gem or library you're trying to use.

Comment: I had this problem with a .gemspec file where I was setting one of my dependencies to a version which was not compatible with my current ruby version. In my case `"some_gem", "~>0"`, which forces the use of `some_gem` version up to 0, but the gem needed 1.x+ for ruby 2.1.